# How to completely erase the duplicated lines by linux tools?

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep, uniq

This question is not equal to [How to print only the unique lines in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740545/how-to-print-only-the-unique-lines-in-bash) because that ones suggests to remove all copies of the duplicated lines, while this one is about eliminating their duplicates only, i..e, change `1, 2, 3, 3` into `1, 2, 3` instead of just `1, 2`.

This question is really hard to write because I cannot see anything to give meaning to it. But the example is clearly straight. If I have a file like this:

```
1
2
2
3
4
```

After to parse the file erasing the duplicated lines, becoming it like this:

```
1
3
4
```

I know python or some of it, this is a python script I wrote to perform it. Create a file called `clean_duplicates.py` and run it as:

```
import sys

#
# To run it use:
# python clean_duplicates.py < input.txt > clean.txt
#
def main():

    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

    # print( lines )
    clean_duplicates( lines )

#
# It does only removes adjacent duplicated lines, so your need to sort them
# with sensitive case before run it.
# 
def clean_duplicates( lines ):

    lastLine    = lines[ 0 ]
    nextLine    = None
    currentLine = None
    linesCount  = len( lines )

    # If it is a one lined file, to print it and stop the algorithm
    if linesCount == 1:

        sys.stdout.write( lines[ linesCount - 1 ] )
        sys.exit()

    # To print the first line
    if linesCount > 1 and lines[ 0 ] != lines[ 1 ]:

        sys.stdout.write( lines[ 0 ] )

    # To print the middle lines, range( 0, 2 ) create the list [0, 1]
    for index in range( 1, linesCount - 1 ):

        currentLine = lines[ index ]
        nextLine    = lines[ index + 1 ]

        if currentLine == lastLine:

            continue

        lastLine = lines[ index ]

        if currentLine == nextLine:

            continue

        sys.stdout.write( currentLine )

    # To print the last line
    if linesCount > 2 and lines[ linesCount - 2 ] != lines[ linesCount - 1 ]:

        sys.stdout.write( lines[ linesCount - 1 ] )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Although, while searching for duplicates lines remove seems to be easier to use tools as grep, sort, sed, uniq:

1. [How to remove duplicate lines inside a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-inside-a-text-file)
2. [removing line from list using sort, grep LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582610/removing-line-from-list-using-sort-grep-linux)
3. [Find duplicate lines in a file and count how many time each line was duplicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated)
4. [Remove duplicate entries in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377040/remove-duplicate-entries-using-a-bash-script)
5. [How to delete duplicate lines in a file without sorting it in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix)
6. [How to delete duplicate lines in a file...AWK, SED, UNIQ not working on my file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039036/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-awk-sed-uniq-not-working-on-my-file)

Comment: Are the duplicate lines always adjacent?  Suppose the input was 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2 — should the 2 after the 4 appear in the output?

Comment: Yes, I sort them before doing it to make it easier to write the code. Anyways, the best is to have used `uniq -u` right away.

Comment: Be aware that given input 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, `uniq -u` will print the second 2; it works only on adjacent duplicate lines.  Pre-sorting is therefore a good idea.  Also note that `uniq` takes zero or one input files, and if there's an input file, it can take an output file: `uniq [-c|-d|-u] [-f fields] [-s char] [input_file [output_file]]` according to POSIX.  It is not a general file filter (a general file filter takes zero or more file names and processes either standard input or each file name in turn, writing to standard output).

Comment: Thanks! The `uniq` doc was misleading. I tested it here, it only remove adjacent lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print only the unique lines in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740545/how-to-print-only-the-unique-lines-in-bash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `uniq` with `-u`/`--unique` option. As per the [`uniq` man page](http://ss64.com/bash/uniq.html):

> `-u`  /  `--unique`
>
> Don't output lines that are repeated in the input.
> Print only lines that are unique in the INPUT.

For example:

```
cat /tmp/uniques.txt | uniq -u
```

OR, as mentioned in [UUOC: Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), better way will be to do it like:

```
uniq -u /tmp/uniques.txt
```

Both of these commands will return me value:

```
1
3
4
```

where */tmp/uniques.txt* holds the number as mentioned in the question, i.e.

```
1
2
2
3
4
```

---

Note: `uniq` requires the content of file to be sorted. As mentioned in [doc](http://ss64.com/bash/uniq.html):

> By default, `uniq` prints the unique lines in a sorted file, it discards all but one of identical **successive input lines**. so that the OUTPUT contains unique lines.

In case file is not sorted, you need to [`sort`](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) the content first
and then use `uniq` over the sorted content:

```
sort /tmp/uniques.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for sharing the info. Updated the answer

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, I guess that was one very important piece of information that I missed, as the content of file in question were already sorted. Updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

No sorting required and output order will be the same as input order:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$0]++;next} c[$0]==1' file file
1
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Europe Finland Office Supplies Online H 5/21/2015 193508565 7/3/2015 2339 651.21 524.96 1523180.19 1227881.44 295298.75
Europe Greece Household Online L 9/11/2015 895509612 9/26/2015 49 668.27 502.54 32745.23 24624.46 8120.77
Europe Hungary Beverages Online C 8/21/2012 722931563 8/25/2012 370 47.45 31.79 17556.50 11762.30 5794.20
Europe Hungary Beverages Online C 8/21/2012 722931563 8/25/2012 370 47.45 31.79 17556.50 11762.30 5794.20
```

If you have this kind of lines you can use this command.

```
[isuru@192 ~]$ sort duplines.txt | sed 's/\ /\-/g' | uniq | sed 's/\-/\ /g'
```

But keep in mind when using special characters. If there dashes in your lines makes sure to use different symbol. Here i keep a space between back & forward slash.

[Before applied the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3wCq.png)

[After applied the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De8IS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use `sort` command with `-u` argument for listing unique values of any command's output.

```
    cat file_name |sort -u
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: This other (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40916868/4934640) answer on this page already cover this.

Answer (score 1):

```
uniq –c your_filename #this will print the count of occurrences 

uniq –u your_filename #prints only unique lines of the file
```